# The right usage of the word pliable

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Pliable has two different meanings. But the pith of the word is flexible. I looked for its meaning on merriam webster dictionary where it is mentioned that pliable person is too easily influenced or controlled by other people which is a negative trait. But in the full definition of the word it is mentioned that a person who is pliable is adjustable which is a positive quality. So, can anyone clear me the meaning in which context the word is more suitable. Two example sentences 
*She sometimes takes advantage of her pliable parents.*          *She's a very pliable kind of person,being able to easily adapt herself to changing situations.*

Comment: When used metaphorically (of a person, meaning "influenceable, receptive"), ***pliable*** usually carries negative associations. If we want positive associations, we'd probably choose an alternative such as ***receptive, adaptable, flexible***. But there are many other ways to convey either nuance - for example, your *pliable parents* could be *acquiescent, amenable, biddable, tractable, complaisant, accommodating, cooperative,...*

Comment: @FumbleFingers I also looked on many other resources and the word pliable has a negative association in the case of personality of a person.

Comment: So what exactly are you asking about here, if you already know that?

Comment: I found its answer after posting the question. Your comment should be a answer to this question.

Comment: It has to do with plying someone with liquor to reduce inhibitions. A pliable person can be induced to do things as if by getting them tipsy. It doesn't really mean flexible, it means willing to be plied. The flexible meaning is just an extension. Pliable materials accept deformation. Plumber's putty and [dooky tape](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS724US727&ei=tRvSXLfvE4nZ8APL14ywBw&q=polybutylene+tape&oq=%22polybutiline+tape%22&gs_l=psy-ab.1.0.0i13i30.10822.18343..21318...0.0..0.590.3064.0j7j2j0j1j2......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i7i30j0i7i10i30.ePpi3uU3h64) are pliable.

Comment: Are you actually asking how to understand what sense of a word is being used when it has multiple senses? The word *pliable* is no different than any other words in that respect—it's just a matter of context. In your question, it makes sense in *both* of your sentences. It's not a question of *more* suitable or not.

Comment: @JasonBassford Sir, Its not about context. I want to know can pliable also be used in a positive sense when talking about the character of a person? and if yes, then how?

Comment: @SudhirSharma The second example sentence in your question *does* use it in a positive sense.

Comment: @JasonBassford So its relevant in both the scenarios. For example, He is very pliable we can easily mend him to work for us. Another example, He is very pliable and will cope with the stressful conditions of workplace.            Are both the sentences correct?

Comment: "He is very pliable we can easily mend him to work for us" doesn't make any sense to me. But *pliable* can mean either *weak and controllable* (negative) or *flexible and adaptable* (positive). As I said originally, it's about context.

Comment: @JasonBassford I apologise,  it should be mold instead of mend. I am not a native speaker so sometimes make mistakes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think the answer is about *how* pliable a person is. This is all referencing flexibility as with wood as you say, or any material and how bendable  it is. The dictionary makes the distinction between those who are flexible and those whose extreme flexibility is an actual character flaw. In an extreme case you might say someone is *spineless*.

Comment: I think spineless is an exteme case of negativity. In general sense pliable is more negative in association with human nature.

Comment: @SudhirSharma On its own, *pliable* expresses neither a negative nor positive trait. The intent behind the use of the word can only be known in context. Speaking only personally, I've generally heard it used in more positive contexts than negative. But you can never know *just from the word alone* how to interpret it.